# WebSocket support for ejabberd

Tags: websocket, xmpp, ejabberd

I am looking to implement WebSocket communication via ejabberd xmpp server...

The only module that I have found so far is this repository:

[ejabberd-websockets](https://github.com/superfeedr/ejabberd-websockets)

This repository has not been updated for 4 year so I do not feel very comfortable using it.

Any alternatives or reviews on above mentioned repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From ejabberd 15.03 version, WebSockets are fully supported, as stated here:

[ejabberd 15.03 released, with Websockets support](https://www.ejabberd.im/node/24818)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [node-xmpp-bosh](https://github.com/dhruvbird/node-xmpp-bosh) which is a node.js based connection manager that sits in front of the XMPP server and handles BOSH and XMPP over WebSockets. The XMPP server sees all traffic as standard XMPP traffic.

I know that the BOSH part works well, but haven't tried WebSockets.

Comment: To the person who downvoted the answer, care to explain? The question was how to make ejabberd work with XMPP over WS and the answer is just that.

Comment: Oleg, I haven't downvoted your answer but this might be an explanation why someone did: BOSH and WebSocket are totally different protocols. BOSH relies completely on HTTP while WebSockets use HTTP only for handshake after which it is directly dependent on TCP.

Comment: @rastko, I know that. The project that I linked to supports _both_